# Adding a new chain to the safe-global/safe-deployments repository?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe-core

I want to deploy the Safe app on a custom EVM-compatible network using [the safe-infrastructure](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure) repository.

What does adding a new chain like [Thundercore Mainnet](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/issues/188) to the [safe-deployments](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments) repository mean in this context?

Can I interpret this to mean that I have completed all my work for my purpose and should now wait for the Safe team to complete the remaining related tasks, such as updating libraries that support the custom network for the safe-infrastructure? If so, how long should I generally expect to wait?

If it is urgent, what actions should I take? Is it necessary to submit a PR to other repositories as shown below besides the safe-deployments repository? What other actions should I take?

- https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/
- https://github.com/safe-global/web-core/
- https://github.com/safe-global/safe-eth-py/
- https://github.com/safe-global/safe-config-service/
- https://github.com/safe-global/safe-transaction-service/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This project contains a collection of deployments of the Safe contracts.
> Adding your chain here means that is going to be available in safe-deployments package to be used in projects like our web interface https://github.com/safe-global/web-core/blob/dev/package.json#L40 but this doesn't means that after that we are going to support this chain. We currently only support 10 chains, because they need to run an infrastructure for each one.
> If you want to run your own infrastructure for your chain you need:
>
> 1. deploy the safe contracts in your chain https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts#deploy
> 2. create an issue and PR with your addresses on safe-deployments
> 3. PR should be provided to safe-eth-py adding the deployment block number and the address (address will be the same for every network) or you can do it later after run safe-infrastructure using the admin panel for transaction service going to the Master Copies and Proxy Factories.
>
> On this point you are ready to run your safe-infrastructure following the guide.

*source: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/issues/211#issuecomment-1485365021*

Answer (score 0):

When adding a new chain like Thundercore Mainnet to the safe-deployments repository, it means that you have completed the initial steps of deploying the Safe app on that network, such as configuring the network parameters and setting up the necessary contracts.

However, there may be additional tasks that need to be completed before the Safe app can be fully supported on that network. This may include updating libraries that support the custom network for the safe-infrastructure, as well as other related repositories like the ones you mentioned.

If you need the Safe app to be supported on the Thundercore Mainnet urgently, you may need to take additional actions to speed up the process. **One option is to submit a pull request (PR) to the relevant repositories with the necessary changes to support the new network. This can help to accelerate the integration process and ensure that the Safe app is fully functional on the new network.**

You may also want to reach out to the Safe team directly to discuss your specific requirements and timeline. They may be able to provide additional guidance or support to help you deploy the Safe app on your custom network as quickly and smoothly as possible.